# Sheets API V4 Spreadsheet View Properties

Tags: google-sheets-api

I'm trying to zoom into a google Spreadsheet using an API call. Is this possible? I would also like to enable full screen from another API call once I dynamically create a spreadsheet, but I can't find it in the documentation, anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: Sounds like you want to perform browser manipulation, not Google sheets manipulation. You'd need a browser extension for that.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the functionality that lets you Zoom in and out the spreadsheets is not supported in [Base Script Services (Class Ui)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui). Also, you have a similar [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48095332/in-google-sheets-how-can-i-script-the-manipulation-of-the-default-zoom), have a check.