# When open Google Spreadsheet from Google Web App, what controls spreadsheet’s visible portion (in web browser)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The following code opens a spreadsheet. What is strange is the portion of the ss that is visible. The ss has around 430 lines (I say "around" as the script adds lines, so how many it has at any given time depends on how many tests I have done of the script and how many of those test lines I have deleted). But, no matter how many lines the ss has or what lines are visible before I run the script or where the cursor is on the ss before I run the script; when the script runs, when the ss first opens, the top portion of the ss is visible (pictured below) and then as the ss is still loading (working), the page redraws and line 396 (or 397, 398, etc., depending on how many tests I have run and/or deleted) is always the first visible line (also pictured).

There is an "onOpen" script that affects the ss (creates a menu), and in order to rule that out as a factor in your minds, it is also reprinted below.

So, what is controlling this redraw process and how do I get it to give me what I want which is to see the bottom of the page? I want this line to be visible as the next logical thing for the user to do after they have added a new song is to add the data for that song.

## Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
      .evaluate();
}
function addSong(objArgs) {
    var id= "1-yN6yAGUuOp84apeN2Cwaq25rPD63qb_m2Oe-MSMaIM"
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
    var url = ss.getUrl();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
    sheet.appendRow([lastRow+1]);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var range = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
    var songTitle = objArgs.songTitle;
    var namedRange = sheet.getRange("Title");
    var newRange = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), namedRange.getColumn())
    var newLastRow = lastRow+1
    newRange.setValue(songTitle);
    url = url + "#gid=1286827341" + "&range=" + newLastRow + ":" + newLastRow;
    Logger.log('url: ' + url)

    return url;
}
```

## Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
<br>Fill in field below with Song Title.<br>
Then click button to add new song to Catalog.<br><br>
    <input id="idSongTitle" type="text" placeholder="Song Title"><br><br>
    <button onclick="saveUserInput()">Add song to Catalog</button>    

    <script>
      window.saveUserInput = function() {
        var songTitle = document.getElementById('idSongTitle').value;
        console.log('songTitle: ' + songTitle)
        google.script.run       
          .withSuccessHandler(openCatalog)
          .addSong({songTitle:songTitle})
      }
       function openCatalog(url){
       window.open(url);
       }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

## Bound Script

## Code.gs

```
/*This menu in use.

This function creates the custom menu. Note: Line 3 throws error, but this script works.*/
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('SP')
      .addItem('Website', 'openSite')
      .addItem('Open Google Drive', 'openDrive')
      .addItem('Open Old SP Site', 'openOldSP')
      .addItem('Create', 'openCreate')
      .addItem('Perform', 'openPerform')
      .addItem('Catalog', 'openCatalog')
      .addItem('New Lyric', 'newLyric')
      .addItem('Add Song to Catalog', 'addSong')
      .addToUi();
}
function openSite() {
  var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var html = "<a href='https://sites.google.com/view/sp-site/catalog'; target='_blank'>Open SP</a>";
  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, 'Open SP');
  }
function openDrive() {
  var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var html = "<a href='https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive'; target='_blank'>Open My Google Drive</a>";
  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, 'Open My Google Drive');
  }
function openOldSP() {
  var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var html = "<a href='url'; target='_blank'>Open Old SP Site</a>";
  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, 'Open My Google Drive');
  }
function openCreate() {
  var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var html = "<a href='url'; target='_blank'>Open Create Spreadsheet</a>";
  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, 'Open Create Sheet');
}
function openPerform() {
  var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var html = "<a href= 'url'; target='_blank'>Open Perform Spreadsheet</a>";
  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, 'Open Perform Sheet');
}
function newLyric() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')
      .setTitle('Create New Landscape Lyric')
      .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showSidebar(html);
}
function createNewLandscapeLyric(objArgs) {
  var docName = objArgs.docName;
  var songTitle = objArgs.songTitle;
  var songWriters = objArgs.songWriters;
  Logger.log(songTitle)
  var doc = DocumentApp.create(docName);
  var url = doc.getUrl();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var paragraph = body.insertParagraph(0, "");
  var text = paragraph.appendText("© "+songWriters);
  text.setFontSize(8);
  var rowsData = [['PUT FIRST VERSE/CHORUS HERE.', 'PUT SECOND VERSE/NEXT CHORUS/BRIDGE/ETC HERE.']];
  var style = {};
  body.insertParagraph(0, songTitle)
  .setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING3);
  table = body.appendTable(rowsData);
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BORDER_WIDTH] = 0;
  table.setAttributes(style);
  Logger.log(url)
  return {
   url: url
  };
}

function addSong() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
    sheet.appendRow([lastRow+1]);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var range = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
    var songTitle = Browser.inputBox('New Song', 'Enter the song title', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
    var namedRange = sheet.getRange("Title");
    var range=sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), namedRange.getColumn())
    range.setValue(songTitle);
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveRange(range);
}
```

## Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
Fill in fields below to name Google Lyric Document and add the song title and writers. Then click button to create new song lyric document.<br><br>
    <input id="idNewDocName" type="text" placeholder="Google Doc Name"><br><br>
    <input id="idNewSongTitle" type="text" placeholder="Song Title"><br><br>
    <input id="idNewSongWriters" type="text" placeholder="Song Writers"><br><br>
    <button onclick="saveUserInput()">Create New Lyric Doc</button>
    <script>
      window.saveUserInput = function() {
        var docName = document.getElementById('idNewDocName').value;
        var songTitle = document.getElementById('idNewSongTitle').value;
        var songWriters = document.getElementById('idNewSongWriters').value;
        console.log('songTitle: ' + songTitle)
        google.script.run       
          .withSuccessHandler(openNewDoc)
          .createNewLandscapeLyric({docName:docName,songTitle:songTitle, songWriters: songWriters})
      }
       function openNewDoc(results){
           window.open(results.url, '_blank').focus();
       }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Spreadsheet browser window when ss first opens

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Final Spreadsheet browser window

[![8][2]][2]

The bottom of the spreadsheet (and BTW, the portion of the ss I would like to see displayed in the browser window when the Web App is through running).

(images removed)

Comment: Is the result the same even when you manually paste the url?

Comment: Great question. Tested it and the answer is the behavior is identical.

Comment: @TheMaster: If I simply zoom out the browser once, all is well (the last row comes into view). I am using FireFox on a Mac. Tested with Chrome and Safari. Same behavior with Chrome, but with Safari, I had default set so that tabs were not visible and the bottom line WAS visible in that case. If I toggle the View menu in Safari and make Tabs visible, the last row is no longer visible. Do you think this is a Google Spreadsheet "error" of sorts or is there some gs code that can fix this? Can the gs code control the browser zoom level?

Comment: Spreadsheet zoom, no: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48095332/in-google-sheets-how-can-i-script-the-manipulation-of-the-default-zoom), but browser zoom?

Comment: Add 500 extra empty rows and try again

Comment: Now wasn't that brilliant!! Worked, of course. How do I mark this answered (or can you?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution to new row not visible:

Just to close the loop on this, I am sure my code is not very elegant, but it works (solves the problem of the new song row not appearing in the visible portion of the browser screen).

## Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
      .evaluate();
}
function addSong(objArgs) {
    var id= "1-yN6yAGUuOp84apeN2Cwaq25rPD63qb_m2Oe-MSMaIM";
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
    var ssUrl = ss.getUrl();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
    var url = ssUrl + "#gid=" + sheetId;
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); //this gets last row at this point in code. "Last row" is defined as last row with content.
    sheet.appendRow([lastRow+1]); //gets prior number and adds 1 row
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var songTitle = objArgs.songTitle; //this pulls the songTitle variable value from Index.html
    var row = sheet.getLastRow(); //this gets row # after new row added
    var colRange = sheet.getRange("Title"); //this gets the Title named column
    var col = colRange.getColumn(); //this gets col # of Title column
    var cell = sheet.getRange(row, col); //this gets the cell reference at the intersection of row and col
    cell.setValue(songTitle);//this puts the songTitle variable value into cell
    var newSongRow = lastRow+1; 
    var C1 = '!C1'; //gets the value in cell C1 calculated on the spreadsheet for the last empty row in column A.
    var lastEmptyRow = sheet.getRange(C1).getValue();
    var padsNeeded = 5; //minimum number of "padded" rows required to force browser window to display the new song row.
    var dif = lastEmptyRow - newSongRow;
    var padChange = padsNeeded-dif;
    var padChangePos = Math.abs(padChange);  
    Logger.log("newSongRow = " + newSongRow);
    Logger.log("lastEmptyRow = " + lastEmptyRow);
    Logger.log("padsNeeded = " + padsNeeded);
    Logger.log("dif = " + dif);
    Logger.log("padChange = " + padChange);
    Logger.log("padChangePos = " + padChangePos);

    if(padChange > 0){
       sheet.insertRowsAfter(newSongRow, padChangePos); 
    } else if (padChange < 0) {
       sheet.deleteRows(newSongRow+1, padChangePos); 
    } 

    var catalogSongsSheet = url + "&range=" + newSongRow + ":" + newSongRow;
    return catalogSongsSheet;


}
```

## Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
<br><center>Fill in field below with Song Title.Then click button to add new song to Catalog.<br><br>
    <input id="idSongTitle" type="text" placeholder="Song Title"><br><br>
    <button onclick="saveUserInput()">Add song to Catalog</button> </center>   

    <script>
      window.saveUserInput = function() {
        var songTitle = document.getElementById('idSongTitle').value;
        console.log('songTitle: ' + songTitle)
        google.script.run       
          .withSuccessHandler(openCatalog)
          .addSong({songTitle:songTitle})
      }
       function openCatalog(url){
       window.open(url);
       }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there was no empty rows after your active range, the scroll stopped at a much higher row(row 398). Add extra rows at the end to automatically scroll to the desired range with the url.

Comment: Hey @TheMaster: One of the things this script is doing is writing a new line number to the cell at the intersection of column 1 (i.e., column A) and the newLastRow. Which is actually behavior I want and require for this script to "work." However, I do not know why this is happening. I.e., which line in the above code is actually doing this?

Comment: sheet.appendRow([lastRow+1]); But, if that's true, it's still a mystery to me why because there is no code finding the column number.

Comment: I ask because I think I am going to use those values (ID numbers) to do an if/then test in order to pad the ss with extra rows to in effect force an add rows process (if there are not sufficient empty rows at the bottom of the ss to ensure that the new row is visible).