# Change default zoom on a Google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, zooming

I use a shared Google sheet to display apparatus issues for a fire department. This is displayed on a tv using an Asus Chromebit. Every time someone logs into the sheet it resets the zoom to 100% which does not fit on the tv. Is there a way to lock the zoom on a specific sheet to 60%?

Comment: Consider to post on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets (better home for this question IMO, you could delete this here and move it there)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Google sheets how can I Script the manipulation of the default Zoom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48095332/in-google-sheets-how-can-i-script-the-manipulation-of-the-default-zoom)